# Android app with database so that people can share data?

Tags: java, android, database

I am designing an android app, the users of which can write a small document, attach some pictures in it, and share to other friends.

I just know Java and C++, and hopefully I can build up the app with Java. However, I have never programmed with other languages, so I have no idea on how to make this app to something that not only users can use individually, but also share some pieces of information they want.

I am very willing to learn new technologies, but not excessively, because of my limited time and money.

How can I do this, and what languages/technologies are needed to accomplish this?

For example, do I need a web page for registration and sign-in, or can I just start without a web page?

Either way, I would definitely need to have a database with a server to make this possible. What technologies do I learn for this?

If people share information, is it necessary to encrypt it, and what should I learn for this?

I am not prepared so I will devote time to learn all these and to be a skilled developer.

Thank you in advance for your advice!

Comment: Your question is too vague. There is so many combinations of technology, and it always depends on particular needs. Think more about how does every technology limit you and on the other hand how it may help you work faster, better, more secure, support more devices, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be more specific, because everything you ask is entirely up to you.  There is over 100 databases you could chose.  You could have a web site, or not. A registration site, or not if you use facebook or another web site.  You could use encryption, or not. If you use it I suggest HTTPS and SSL as these are standard.

---

> For example, do I need a web page for registration and sign-in, or can I just start without a web page?

Yes, either.

> Either way, I would definitely need to have a database with a server to make this possible. What technologies do I learn for this?

You need to learn how to use a database, and how to manage a server.  Perhaps a bit about hardware.

> If people share information, is it necessary to encrypt it, and what should I learn for this?

I wouldn't start with encryption unless you want to secure the data.  You can do this later.

Comment: Thank you! So, you mean it's possible to make people register for my service on their phones and no website is necessary, right? Can I just start with something like this: when user A touches the 'share' button to share a document(not exactly a document.. something more like a memo?, but I will just call it document here) with his friends B and C, the document is sent through email as an attachment, and if B is a user of my app, he can import the attachment into his app, and C is not, and he can do nothing?(maybe can read it as html form or sth, but it may be too hard) - Will this be easier?

Comment: This is what Google Drive does, so all that is possible. (if not done already ;)

Comment: and will this be more secure, or less?(obviously it's a less convenient way and if sharing data within my database is not too difficult or costly, I would definitely want to do that)

Comment: There are many aspects to security.  I would worry more about hackers who attempt to obtain all the documents in your database by hacking your system.  You should make the client end reasonably secure, but your system has to be far more secure.  Note: using a single database is unlikely to scale very well. Google, for example, use over one million servers around the world.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will start learning database and managing server(hope they're not too hard), and some Ruby!

Comment: IMHO One of the simplest databases to use is MySQL.  This will give you a starting point.

Comment: I would also ask yourself what products are out there which do something similar to what you are doing and what ideas you can get from them.  Also ask yourself what you are doing differently which will make people choice your solution.

Answer (score 3):

This may help you: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html (Saving Data in SQL Databases)

Just refer to the android developers site, and you may find that most of your cases will be solved! ^_^